# Can a paypal-ipn be received by a controller action in grails

Tags: grails, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I need to integrate paypal subscription in our grails application.

I have created the subscription button in sandbox. I have created a controller action and provided the corresponding url in the button ipn.

The payments are happening successfully and also emails notifications are being sent. But the action is not getting called by the ipn.

Is it that the ipn url cannot be a controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Is that url accessible from the outside? Paypal will call your url after the subscription from their webservers, therefore your server must be accessible from the internet.

Comment: Yes. I have accessed the url from a web browser. Within the action I have specified some print statements which get printed on the server console. While accessing the url manually the statements are getting printed. But nothing is printed when the url is used for notifications.

Comment: So the url does not point to your localhost? Try to access it from another computer that is not in the same local network as yours and make sure that there is no firewall or anything blocking access.

Comment: I have tried accessing it from a different computer. Access does take place.